# How to plot a vectorized graph in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a dataframe or np.array and want to plot a vectorized (i.e. infinitely zoomable a.k.a. non rasterized image) graph.

I want it to be as simple as matplotlib (by that I mean you can plot multiple graphs on the same figure, subplots, etc).

I have already tried Plotly but found it too complicated, correct me if I'm wrong though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use interactive plots if start your notebook using the `%matplotlib widget` magic method at the top of the first cell. Make sure you have `ipympl` installed in your environment. Here is an example with an illustration:

```py
%matplotlib widget
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randn(100, 2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(*data.T, 'o')
```

And it will generate an interactive figure in which you can pan and zoom etc. using mouse gestures or the UI shown to the left of the chart below:
[image]

Comment: It may be easier for those new to `ipympl` use to remember what package needs to be installed by specifying the backend as `%matplotlib ipympl`. They both work according to [here](https://matplotlib.org/ipympl/#basic-example): "To activate the `ipympl` backend all you need to do is include the `%matplotlib ipympl` magic in the notebook. Alternatively you can use `%matplotlib widget` which will have the same effect."

Comment: Thanks! It's still quite glitchy though. It constantly crashes, and it freezes when restarting the kernel, so I need to reopen VSCode. Also, when I re-run a cell (re-plotting the graph), it simply doesn't show anymore